# How to I display images next to each other in jasper reports in jaspersoft studio in the detail view without the pages multiplying?

Tags: jasper-reports

At the moment the same images is displaying under each other in the detail section and the pages multiply by how many images there is.()

This is the code I tried(I did in jaspersoft studio):

```
<detail>
        <band height="111">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetLayout"/>
            <image hAlign="Left">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="390" height="111" uuid="8bf21ae9-eec4-4c39-b4c1-4c174ec59aab">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{photo_blob}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

This is the sql script:

```
<queryString>
        <![CDATA[select distinct job_card.job_card_name,
job_card.job_number,
job_card.job_type,
job_card.job_card_name,
client_account.account_name,
job_card.punchlist_comments,
"user".name,
job_card.customer_name,
job_card.created_at,
job_card.customer_signature_blob,
job_card.technician_signature_blob,
photograph.photo_blob
from $P!{schemaName}.job_card
left join $P!{schemaName}.photograph on $P!{schemaName}.job_card."_id_" = $P!{schemaName}.photograph.job_cards_fk
left join $P!{schemaName}."user" on $P!{schemaName}."user"."_id_" = $P!{schemaName}.job_card.technicians_fk
left join $P!{schemaName}.asset on $P!{schemaName}.asset."_id_" = $P!{schemaName}.job_card.assets_fk
left join $P!{schemaName}.client_account on $P!{schemaName}.client_account."_id_" = $P!{schemaName}.asset.clientaccounts_fk
where job_card._id_ = $P{job_cardUUID}::uuid
;]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="job_card_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="job_number" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="job_type" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="account_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="punchlist_comments" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="customer_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="created_at" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="customer_signature_blob" class="java.awt.Image"/>
    <field name="technician_signature_blob" class="java.awt.Image"/>
    <field name="photo_blob" class="java.awt.Image"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, same question, same answer.
[image]