# How to make different pictures display on jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a issue where the same picture displays when trying to display three seperate images from a "job card" in this case..

[image]

but there are actually three different images on the db

this is my SQL:

```
    select distinct job_card.job_card_name,
job_card.job_number,
job_card.job_type,
job_card.job_card_name,
client_account.account_name,
job_card.punchlist_comments,
"user".name,
job_card.customer_name,
job_card.created_at,
job_card.customer_signature_blob,
job_card.technician_signature_blob,
photograph.photo_blob
from $P!{schemaName}.job_card
left join $P!{schemaName}.photograph on $P!{schemaName}.job_card."_id_" = $P!{schemaName}.photograph.job_cards_fk
left join $P!{schemaName}."user" on $P!{schemaName}."user"."_id_" = $P!{schemaName}.job_card.technicians_fk
left join $P!{schemaName}.asset on $P!{schemaName}.asset."_id_" = $P!{schemaName}.job_card.assets_fk
left join $P!{schemaName}.client_account on $P!{schemaName}.client_account."_id_" = $P!{schemaName}.asset.clientaccounts_fk
where job_card._id_ = $P{job_cardUUID}::uuid
```

"photograph.photo_blob" being the variable

and this is the jasper elements:

```
<textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[ Installation pictures ]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <image>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="180" width="200" height="124" uuid="8bf21ae9-eec4-4c39-b4c1-4c174ec59aab"/>
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                            </box>
                            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{photo_blob}]]></imageExpression>
                        </image>
                        <image>
                            <reportElement x="200" y="180" width="200" height="124" uuid="aa9d55fb-184f-4098-95f8-9de17530c99b"/>
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                            </box>
                            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{photo_blob}]]></imageExpression>
                        </image>
                        <image>
                            <reportElement x="400" y="180" width="150" height="124" uuid="64df2d59-4154-4b26-a3d1-3f54f1b54eca"/>
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                            </box>
                            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{photo_blob}]]></imageExpression>
                        </image>
```

I tried putting this box in the detail band but the page just multiplies by the amount of pictures

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/65342983/876298 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/65307252/876298

Answer (score 0):

You have three repeated pictures because you are using three image elements in the same band at the same time, sharing the same expression i.e `$F{photo_blob}`.

If you have tree or more different pictures for every `job_card._id_` you must create a group, say `job_card`, and in the group header you put

```
<text><![CDATA[ Installation pictures ]]></text>
```

And in the detail band you put

```
<image>
    <reportElement x="0" y="180" width="200" height="124" uuid="8bf21ae9-eec4-4c39-b4c1-4c174ec59aab"/>
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
    </box>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{photo_blob}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Comment: this multiplies the pages by the amount of pictures on the DB

Comment: do you see any duplicates? Do you have different pictures for the same job_card._id_ below the rest of the data? If you say yes, you are in the right path, needing only make your report print in horizontal order, and put some more columns. as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/65342983/876298